# pros and cons to use session in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

First things first, I'm just a starter.

It seems that Session is something MS not recommend anymore, by using RESTFUL website, model would always be the first choice to submit all the values, and maybe in the future they will remove that concept

But, my question is, you cannot rely on model to store everything about users,  there must be some case session will be the best way, for example:

1. there is a payment list page and session will be the best way to store the keywords, Caz every time use click page number, they don't submit to controller, so there is no way to get those information by server side(they not passed at all).
2. If we building a online shopping site by ASP MVC, the session can also be used as cart, if we store in database.

So I'm kind of confusing whether or not to use session, can any body give me some ideas about the best practices of session?

Comment: `It seems that Session is something MS not recommend anymore, by using RESTFUL website` ***Could you post the URL?***

Comment: The primary reason sessions are not recommended anymore is that they introduce server-side state. This makes it very difficult to scale an app horizontally because all your servers will need to work with a single session store. REST doesn't really have anything to do with sessions, but it does advocate statelessness.

Comment: This thread discusses RESTful authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270393/how-do-i-implement-authentication-the-restful-way  (Personally I believe HTTPS/Basic risks the password unnecessarily)  **Con:** Payment necessitates authentication.  Authentication will likely be more difficult without a session.

Answer (score 3):

A `Session` is still created. The `Session` is leveraged from IIS. Just because it's a `REST` service doesn't mean there is no session, it means that it leverages the HTTP verbs (e.g. `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE`) rather than a `WSDL` and `SOAP` to perform operations.

`REST` is an architecture, not a technology.

Even with a `REST` service you could do something like this:

```
var cart = Session["Cart"] as ShoppingCart;
cart.AddItem(...);
```

and you could get the values for `AddItem` via a `POST` request.

Comment: Not to mention user authentication.  It would certainly be a pain to have to log-in on every page request because there was no session to show you had already logged in.  (I suppose the client could re-post a security token each request, but that seems an extreme only necessary for load-balanced environments that can't handle the most basic of session sharing)

Comment: @ebyrob what does session have to do with user authentication? A Session is/can be created regardless of whether the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: @Icarus, the very act of authentication doesn't have anything to do with a `Session`. True. But generally speaking you hold information surrounding that user in `Session`. I'm pretty sure that's what he was referring to, and that's what I was thinking of.

Comment: @TheSolution That's exactly it.  Without a session you can't store even a single bit of data between page-requests.  The single most important flag I can think of is IsUserLoggedIn, followed closely by WhichUserIsLoggedIn.  I suppose you could try to store something in the DB, but then you're just pushing the idea of session into the DB, and I can only think of problems with that scenario.  (Verifiable tokens will solve this problem, but there's some definite effort to get tokens right, and anything that relies much on client processing to get things right is a bit suspect in my book.)